# What biblical (scriptural) basis does a Christian have to command the blessings?

Tags: biblical-basis

I hear some Christians say that we should command the blessings or command our morning to align itself with our day and faith. I believe this is true, but I want a biblical framework to reference when this topic comes about. I believe the kingdom is based on Kingdom principles, and when we act in faith upon these biblical principles, it becomes the key that unlocks Heaven's riches to us.  However, it's something I just believe, but where is that found? How do I explain this theory to a newbie, or a young believer in Christ from a scriptural basis?

Comment: This sounds like an OK question, but let me rephrase it. You are asking how you - as a faithful follower of Christ - can "command the blessings"? Can you narrow down specifically what you want? It may be too broad or too Bible Study-like.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: I don't understand what "command the blessing" means, either.

Comment: I think this is insider lingo for the "name it and claim it" crowd.  Perhaps we need a Word of Faith expert to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

There is none to support commanding our God to do anything. Would you walk into court and command a judge to reduce your sentence? Absolutely not, you would ask respectfully and explain your circumstance.

The same would go for your fleshly father. If you needed something all you have to do is ask respectfully. What father wouldn't give his children something they needed? How much more so our heavenly father. This is demonstrated by Jesus at **Luke 11:11-13:**

> *"Indeed, which father among you, if his son asks for a fish, will hand him a serpent instead of a fish?12  Or if he also asks for an egg, will hand him a scorpion? 13  Therefore, if you, although being wicked, know how to give good gifts to your children, how much more so will the Father in heaven give holy spirit to those asking him!”*

Then at **Matthew 6:32**

> *"For all these are the things the nations are eagerly pursuing. Your heavenly Father knows that you need all these things."*

So we see that God knows what we need and is eager to give it to us when we ask. If we want to show our love for god we show "fear" or respect for him. This means asking and not demanding. When we command something to happen, it is as if by our own hands or power we can make it happen. When we do that we take away from the glory of our father. Look at the example made of Moses when he didn't glorify god at **numbers 20:10**. We don't want to take the credit for something god does. We show humility and meekness by just asking and those are qualities God finds very favorable.

Answer (score 3):

One passage often used to defend this doctrine is the words of Jesus in [Mark 11:23-24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%2011:23-24&version=NIV):

> “Truly I tell you, if anyone says to this mountain, ‘Go, throw
>   yourself into the sea,’ and does not doubt in their heart but believes
>   that what they say will happen, it will be done for them. Therefore I
>   tell you, whatever you ask for in prayer, believe that you have
>   received it, and it will be yours."

Answer (score 1):

The book of Job is where it is found.  Job is the one who's speaking.  He asked one of his friends if he commanded the morning to line up with God's word.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. The community here prefers longer answers. Please see [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer) After that, please [edit] this post to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 1):

The basis for the "command the blessings" belief is through a sort of "literal and no-exceptions" interpretation of passages like these:

> **Matthew 7:7-8 ESV** Ask, and it will be given to you; seek, and you will find; knock, and it will be opened to you. For everyone who asks receives, and the one who seeks finds, and to the one who knocks it will be opened.
>
> **John 14:13 ESV** Whatever you ask in my name, this I will do, that the Father may be glorified in the Son.
>
> **John 16:23-24 ESV** In that day you will ask nothing of me. Truly, truly, I say to you, whatever you ask of the Father in my name, he will give it to you. Until now you have asked nothing in my name. Ask, and you will receive, that your joy may be full.
>
> **Matthew 21:21-22 ESV** And Jesus answered them, “Truly, I say to you, if you have faith and do not doubt, you will not only do what has been done to the fig tree, but even if you say to this mountain, ‘Be taken up and thrown into the sea,’ it will happen. And whatever you ask in prayer, you will receive, if you have faith.”

---

EXTRA: While out of the scope of your question, it's worth saying that the "command your blessings" belief is just another version of "name it, claim it", which more or less treats God like he is a genie from a magic lamp. It's important to append the above passages to ones like this:

> **James 4:1-3 ESV** What causes quarrels and what causes fights among you? Is it not this, that your passions are at war within you? You desire and do not have, so you murder. You covet and cannot obtain, so you fight and quarrel. You do not have, because you do not ask. You ask and do not receive, **because you ask wrongly**, to spend it on your passions.

Answer (score 1):

The commanding the morning and commanding God teachings are set in word of faith doctrine and most definitely not Biblical and by that I mean that they are a distortion of scripture.   Job 38:12  God is asking Job the question have you commanded the morning since your days began or shown the Dawn its place.  God is making a point  and addressing Job's arrogance; Job had lived to see many mornings but never had the power to command one.  What God is asking Job is did you create the sun and appoint the order of succession of day and night. If we read the book of Job we get the true meaning of this verse that is so blatantly torn out of its original context.  Several teachers and preachers seem to believe this doctrine which however if researched and lined up with scripture is seen to be false and more in line with mysticism and new age beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

The closest verse i can think of is Isaiah 45:11 " Thus saith the LORD, the Holy One of Israel, and his Maker, Ask me of things to come concerning my sons, and concerning the work of my hands command ye me".

Comment: Hm. My version has "Thus says the LORD, the Holy One of Israel, and his Maker: ‘Will you question me about my children, or command me concerning the work of my hands?’" and implies the answer **No** because of the next verse: "I made the earth, and created man upon it; it was my hands that stretched out the heavens, and I commanded all their host."

Comment: @AndrewLeach the KJV does, in fact, read what Reg Ofori posted. It's God is telling Cyrus basically "Go ahead, COMMAND me! TRY IT!" Not as a serious "command me", but because of how He is implying His control over man. As in verse 9 of this chapter: "Woe unto him that striveth with his Maker! Let the potsherd strive with the potsherds of the earth. Shall the clay say to him that fashioneth it, What makest thou? or thy work, He hath no hands?"

Answer (score 0):

The "command your morning" scripture is actually based on Job 38:12-13:

"Have you ever given orders to the morning, or shown the dawn its place, that it might take the earth by the edges and shake the wicked out of it?"

Note that some versions like the KJV use "commanded" instead of "given orders to". You can judge for yourself if this is a sufficient basis for this belief.

Comment: But the thought behind the question asked is the implied answer of "No, you haven't, because you are not God." It might be a verse used out of ignorance, though.

Comment: I first saw the "command the morning" idea in a pamphlet by an African Christian. In fact, right now if you Google the concept, you will find prayers written for that purpose such as the one on this link: http://www.newbirth.org/download/PRAYERS_TO_COMMAND_THE_MORNING.pdf

Comment: Here's the African writer that I read that discussed the idea:  Dr. D. K. Olukoya and his book on the subject on Amazon. Not saying that he is correct, but just attributing that this doctrine is taught by him and is his interpretation of a particular text or verses of scripture: http://www.amazon.com/Command-Morning-Dr-D-Olukoya/dp/9783691783